# Keep an icon in place after the user entered a text in an input

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to transition a search icon and an input placeholder in the input, so when the user "focuses" on the input, the placeholder and the search icon gets pushed to the left side using a transition, I have no problem so far except... When I type in the input I want the icon to stay where it is after it has been focused, **if there's text inside the input**. So right now if you type in a text and then click out of the input of course the icon is gonna go back to it's original position because the user "blured" out of the input.

I want the icon to stay on the left, only and only if there's text inside the input.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search stuff...">
<svg height="32px" width="32px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="search-icon">
    <g id="Page-1" fill="none" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1">
        <g id="icon-111-search">
            <path id="search" d="M19.4271164,21.4271164 C18.0372495,22.4174803 16.3366522,23 14.5,23 C9.80557939,23 6,19.1944206 6,14.5 C6,9.80557939 9.80557939,6 14.5,6 C19.1944206,6 23,9.80557939 23,14.5 C23,16.3366522 22.4174803,18.0372495 21.4271164,19.4271164 L27.0119176,25.0119176 C27.5621186,25.5621186 27.5575313,26.4424687 27.0117185,26.9882815 L26.9882815,27.0117185 C26.4438648,27.5561352 25.5576204,27.5576204 25.0119176,27.0119176 L19.4271164,21.4271164 L19.4271164,21.4271164 Z M14.5,21 C18.0898511,21 21,18.0898511 21,14.5 C21,10.9101489 18.0898511,8 14.5,8 C10.9101489,8 8,10.9101489 8,14.5 C8,18.0898511 10.9101489,21 14.5,21 L14.5,21 Z" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
#search-input {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ECECEC;
  background: #FCFCFC;
  text-indent: 23px;
  outline: none;
}

#search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 45px;
  transition: padding 0.2s;
}

#search-input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#search-icon {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 8px;
  transition: left 0.2s;
}

#search-input:focus + #search-icon {
  left: 10px;
}

#search-icon path {
  fill: #666;
}
```

**I have the pen right [here](https://codepen.io/AkarM13/pen/opZNOg).**

I don't mind including JavaScript into the solution since it's a SPA, and it's a React project so React related solutions are preferred but not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that I can think of is:

- Converting :focus modifier css into classes.
- Adding two events to search-input onFocus and onblur
- Add the classes in the onfocus callbacks and remove in the onblur
  callback only if the input box is empty.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, I am waiting on code solutions, if there isn't anyone else I am gonna confirm it.

Comment: I've implemented that solution, and confirmed your solution.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `:placeholder-shown` but https://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder-shown

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: I know of that solution but it doesn't support many browsers.